# draw rectangle in millimeters doesn't show accurate width

Tags: c#

I am drawing a rectangle in millimeter on a panel using the following code in c# by entering the width and length in mm at runtime. However the resultant rectangle drawn varies in size in different monitors. I want the rectangle to appear same size irrespective of the running the app in any monitor. Can any1 help me?. currently the width for 10mm measures 12mm and length for 10mm shows 11mm using a scale. I tested the app on different monitors, there again it shows different length. Is their anyway that I can show it to be of same width and length?

```
void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    SolidBrush ygBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.YellowGreen);
    g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

    int w = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text.ToString());
    int h = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text.ToString());

    rct = new Rectangle(94, 27, w, h);
    g.FillRectangle(ygBrush, rct);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most displays aren't properly configured so that the computer knows the DPI (dots-per-inch).  Physical units like millimeters only work if the computer knows how many pixels are *in* a millimeter, both horizontally and vertically.

Essentially, the method you're using is correct - but you're very unlikely in the real world to come across properly-configured machines.

If you needed to solve this problem in your software you could perhaps include a "configuration" option where the user would be responsible for setting the scale of the application.

Comment: Thank you. But I tested the app in 3 different machines and also checked the DPI value of those monitors by retrieving it through g.DPIX. The value was 96dpi. Is there any parameter that changes with different monitors or different screen resolution. I did use other options like GetDeviceCaps(), Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds also. I am not able to understand exactly which parameter varies with different machines or at least the app should work properly for different resolutions.

Comment: No, this is my point: dpi is rarely accurate, and it's even rarer that someone would properly configure their system.  Remember: the machine itself has no way of knowing what size display it's connected to.  EG: at home I have a 24" and a 26" monitor, both running at the same resolution.  The DPI on each monitor is different - but Windows has no idea of this.  Your software *could never work* as required on my machine until I personally tell Windows about the difference in my displays.  If you factor in resolution changes as well, this problem becomes even more complex...